# Sum of values for a given day

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a sheet that is tracking the cost of transactions ordered by date. I would like to achieve these results:

[image: (http://imgur.com/TJxzKyi)]

for the 'Daily Total' column.

In other words, for the last row of a given date, the cell in the Column C will hold the total value of transactions for that day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this in C2:

```
=IF(A2<> A3,SUMIF(A:A,A2,B:B),"")
```

And copy down.

Comment: Works perfectly, I will accept your answer as soon as I can. As an addition to my question - is it possible to add a new column that prints the weekly total (Monday - Sunday) in the row of the last transaction on each Sunday?

Comment: Yup but that is a different question, and new question deserve their own post. But, You would use Weekday in the if: `=IF(AND(WEEKDAY(A2)=0,A2<>A3),...  Then use a SUMIFS that uses two criteria <=A1 and >=A1-6.  try to make it work with this info.  If it does not work then past another question.

Comment: To use two criteria in a SUMIF, do you use an AND?

Comment: I have posted a new question.